# Error importing vmdk files using ec2 developer tools

Tags: amazon-ec2, ec2-api-tools

Although vmdk disk format is supported by ec2-import-instance tool, every time I try to run the command on a vmdk file, I get the following error:

```
    ERROR: File uses unsupported compression algorithm 0
```

I invoke the tool in the following format:

```
    ec2-import-instance -f vmdk -o <ACCESS KEY> -w <SECRET KEY> <VMDK file>
```

I am using ec2 tools version 1.6.6.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it's got nothing to do with "compression algorithm" but instead more to do with supported vmdk formats as documented in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/VMImportPrerequisites.html

Comment: How did you actually solve the problem? I am facing the same problem with an vmdk from VMware Fusion 6. I fear the ec migration tools don't support the latest formats from vmware.

Comment: I'm also quite eager to hear if you've cracked this

Answer (score 1):

ERROR: File uses unsupported compression algorithm 0.
The VMDK was created using OVA format instead of OVF format.

Resolution

Create the VMDK in OVF format.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this for myself by exporting my VM from VirtualBox(where I created it). This exported its into OVF format(I had to change the default exention from OVA to OVF). Then ec2-import-instance worked.

[This](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=552284) put me on the right track when converting to RAW using qemu-img did not work.

Answer (score 0):

This ec2 migration tool works with both VMware workstation and ESX
http://cloudscraper.migrate2iaas.com/
Just run it from your running server.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same issue. My solution: the StarWind V2V converter to convert VMDK to RAW (-f RAW) or VHD (-f VHD).