# ec2-import-instance throws ERROR: File uses unsupported compression algorithm 0 when importing vmdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-api-tools

Trying to import a vmdk to AWS and I keep on getting this error. Not sure why? I checked everything in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/VMImportPrerequisites.html but nothing works.

Not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error importing vmdk files using ec2 developer tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14511202/error-importing-vmdk-files-using-ec2-developer-tools)

Comment: Thanks, I checked that one but could not figure out the error based on the information in the earlier thread.

Answer (score 0):

This error message is explained in [Troubleshooting VM Import/Export](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/VMImportTroubleshooting.html#ErrorUnsupportedCompressionAlgorithm)